# removing timeout for services that take a lot of time

Tags: wcf

I call a WCF service from withing a Windows Workflow framework service.

Windows Workflow framework is designed expecially for long rnning tasks. So I call the service that may take 5minutes or up to 2 hours to complete the job. But I get a timeout on the client. Can I eliminate the timeout constraint?

Comment: Please share the pertinent bits from both your client side and service side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the binding section of the config on the service and client side you can set the recieveTimeout, sendTimeout, openTimout, and closeTimeout

```
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ExampleService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                     openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
```

Comment: Make sure the values on the client are less than or equal to the same values on the service side, otherwise you may not end up with the results you expect.  i.e. the client can not specify a timeout longer than one the service configures.

Comment: Actually, the client *can* specify a timeout longer than the service timeout, but anything longer than the service timeout will be ignored.